# how to dispatch message to channels with int-ftp spring integration?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

thanks for attention,
i used `int-ftp:outbound-gateway`  to ls command on ftp server , i want to process output channel and dispatch to other channel , my code is:

```
<int:channel id="inbound1"/>

    <int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
                              session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                              request-channel="inbound1"
                              command="ls"
                              command-options="-R"
                              expression="payload"
                              reply-channel="output"/>
    <int:channel id="output">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>
```

**how proccess output channel and dispatch to other channel for example input1 and input2?**

Comment: It is not clear what your requirements are; you can add a `<splitter/>` to break the list into individual files, then use a `<router/>`. I suggest you read the [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/), look at the [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) then come back here when you have a specific question.

Comment: thanks for reply @Gary,i want to rout messages into several channels that are separate operation sequence.

Comment: That still doesn't help me; please update your question with a __clear__ explanation of your problem and/or what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for fast reply @Gary,i want to dispatch output channel to output1,output2 channels and i want to process output channel for example DispatcherClass for determine,how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear what you want to do. Please explain in more detail, with examples - update the question rather than adding a long comment here.