# how to set filename-pattern option in int-ftp:outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

firstly. thanks for attention,
i defined ftp adapter in my spring integration project , i set `filename-pattern` to "*.in" to filter `.in` extension in int-ftp:outbound-gateway with ls command, i am sure that exists files with `.in` extension but return empty list,my code is:

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
                              session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                              request-channel="inbound"
                              command="ls"
                              filename-pattern="*.in"
                              command-options="-R"
                              expression="payload"
                              reply-channel="toSplitter"/>
```

**Update**
i defined a outbound-channel-adapter to consume the channel as bellow:

```
<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="toSplitter" method="handle">
        <bean class="ir.ali.integration.handler.Dispatcher"/>
    </int:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

my bean is:

```
@Component
public class Dispatcher {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mvChannel")
    private MessageChannel messageChannel;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("toGet")
    private MessageChannel messageChannel1;

    public void handle(List<FileInfo> value) {
        for (FileInfo fileInfo : value) {

            Message<FileInfo> fileInfoMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(fileInfo).build();
            if (FileUtil.isExists("./backup/".concat(fileInfo.getFilename()))) {
                messageChannel.send(fileInfoMessage);
            } else {
                messageChannel1.send(fileInfoMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but not working and return empty list and i added a bellow line in `for` to handle it:

```
if (!FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileInfo.getFilename()).equals("in"))
            continue;
```

but not worked correctly

Comment: First, remove the attribute to verify you actually receive any files with that pattern. Note that this is a filter that's applied after we've received the files pointed to by `payload` (in your case). If you do in fact receive such files, show the list here (edit the question, don't post a list in the comment).

Comment: @Gary above problem combine two issue that [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769810/how-to-dispatch-message-to-channels-with-int-ftp-spring-integration)

Comment: Like I said, remove the pattern to see what you get - I can't teach you how to debug your code. You should use a router instead of your custom code - please read the reference documentation.

Comment: ok thanks @Gary, i read the reference